# Ignoring unlabeled data for a single class

Tags: classification, class-imbalance, semi-supervised-learning

I have a data set of transactions with a binary flag labeling each as fraud or not fraud. However, it can take up to 90 days for a transaction to reveal itself as fraudulent. Sometimes it happens in a few days.

I can safely use any data older than 90 days as we are 100% confident the labels are accurate. However, for the 90 day window, anything that has been classified as fruad we are 100% certain is right, but anything labeled not fraud we cannot say with confidence as not enough time has passed for fraud to come through the payment system.

What are the dangers of adding any of the **known fraud from that 90-day window** to the **older known and completely labeled data set** for training a classifier, **while ignoring any "unknown" transactions** within that 90-day window? Obviously, this seems to be a great task for semi-supervised learning, just wondering what big errors and bias this would cause.

Fraud of Txs Over Time:

0000100001100000100000001010010000 **||** **90 days ago** **||** 1????11??1?1????1
Which turns into:
0000100001100000100000001010010000 **||** **90 days ago** **||** 111111

Comment: What comes to my mind: Is there a reason to believe that the data generating process changes over time? I say this because if what characterizes fraud is stable over time, you may not have a problem adding the „for sure no fraud“ data (you kind of oversample this class then). However, if there is an important time dimension, your model may learn a „wrong“ representation of „no fraud“ if you add more recent data.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I agree with what yo uare saying, which is why currently (without any semi-supervised labeling) I would simply ignore all recent "no fraud" flags and keep any "fraud" as we know that label is correct. The process that labels a Tx as fraud comes through different payment processes and randomly gets filled in over that 90-day window.

Comment: So I guess the time dimension is a serious danger (if relevant). Maybe you can check this? I would be really cautious here. Maybe you should ask: what is the benefit of including more recent „no fraud“ data?

Comment: Essentially, the confidence that fraud=0 increases as is gets older, and by the time it hits 90 days it's 100% (or very very high) that it is NOT fraud. So not toally random, as I first said. But, any fraud flag might come in at 0 days or 90 days, we just can't say for sure since we are not in control of those systems. The only thing we can say with 100% certainly of tx data in the 90-day window are those that have already been labeled as fraudulent.